# CMake generator expressions evaluations order

Tags: c++, cmake

I wanna make a shared library from an object library but I don't know when the generator expressions are evaluating during the generation process. In this example :

```
add_library(foo OBJECT foo.c)
add_library(boo SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foo>)
target_sources(foo PRIVATE boo.c)
```

The boo shared lib will contain `boo.c` or not ?

Comment: why not add boo.c to add_library call directly ?

Comment: @Noki : Because in my case it's more complicated, there are files and sub directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=generator

> Generator expressions are evaluated during build system generation to produce information specific to each build configuration.
>
> ...
>
> This means that they enable conditional linking, conditional definitions used when compiling, and conditional include directories and more. The conditions may be based on the build configuration, target properties, platform information or any other queryable information.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, the boo.c is in the boo lib. I saved your time :)